# Summation Proof Clarification/Hint

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, summation

Hi Im stuck on this step of a problem and we don't know how to simplify it further. We are pretty sure it is all supposed to sum to zero. Here is where we are: 
We are trying to figure out if the sum of residuals is zero if $$\beta_0 = 0$$ 
We started out with $$\sum_{i=0}^n e_i= \sum_{i=0}^n (y_i - (\hat\beta_1 \cdot x_i))$$ We solved for beta $$\hat\beta_1 = \sum_{i=0}^n y_i - \frac{\sum_{i=0}x_iy_i}{\sum_{i=0}x_i^2}$$ Then plugged the equation in which results in this equation
$$\sum_{i=0}^n y_i - \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n x_iy_i \cdot \sum_{i=0}^n x_i} {\sum_{i=0}^n x_i^2}$$
I am pretty sure its zero sometimes but not others but I need a push in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: It might help to answer your question if you would post the initial starting point or the steps that made you end up here. And what are $x_i$ and $y_i$ and does it matter?

Comment: Gave some more information :)

Answer (score 1):

This expression is not necessarily 0. Counterexample:

$x_0 = 1\\y_0=3\\x_1=2\\y_1=5$

$\Sigma = y_0+y_1 - \frac{(x_0 y_0 + x_1 y_1)(x_0+x_1)}{x_0^2+x_1^2}\\=8 - \frac{(3+10)(1+2)}{1+4}\\=8-\frac{39}{5}$

I'm guessing the origin of the $x_i$ and $y_i$ is very important to the behavior of these sums.

Comment: +1 I was thinking about counterexamples, this one is good.